# Parent Checkbox iterate through first of children then stop

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a parent checkboxes and children. When I select the top level parent, the children also are selected as I would expect. However, all the children of the other parents also are checked. I would like it to stop at the next parent without the next level children being checked.

```js
$(".ParentsourcefileCheckBox").click(function() {
  var Titletextbox = $(this)
    .closest("tr")
    .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
    .val();
  var myRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
    rowWithInput = myRow.nextAll(":has('.ChildsourcefileCheckBox')"),
    val = rowWithInput.find(".ChildsourcefileCheckBox").val();
  if (
    $(this)
    .closest("tr")
    .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
    .is(":checked")
  ) {
    rowWithInput
      .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
      .prop("checked", true);
    rowWithInput
      .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
      .attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    rowWithInput
      .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
      .prop("checked", false);
    rowWithInput
      .find("input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]")
      .attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-framed" id="seconDTable" style="display:block;height: 100%;">
  <tbody id="secondtbody">
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="checker" id="uniform- CheckBox">
          <span>
            <input
              title="Select All Bookmarks"
              class="styled"
              id="CheckBox"
              type="checkbox"
              permission="0"
            />
          </span>
        </div>
        <span>Select All</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ParentsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="LEAD Technologies" permission="0" />
        <span>LEAD Technologies</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="About LEAD Technologies" permission="0" />
        <span>About LEAD Technologies</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Fast Facts" permission="0" />
        <span>Fast Facts</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Developer Tools" permission="0" />
        <span>Developer Tools</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Imaging Applications/Utilities" permission="0" />
        <span>Imaging Applications/Utilities</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ParentsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Why Use LEADTOOLS" permission="0" />
        <span>Why Use LEADTOOLS</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Time-Tested" permission="0" />
        <span>Time-Tested</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="One SDK Vendor Who Does it All!" permission="0" />
        <span>One SDK Vendor Who Does it All!</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you need to have that complex table structure? Is this something that could be changed?

Comment: Unfortunalety, it's the elements of the bookmarks of a PDF

Comment: It is a shame, the code could be simplified a lot without that table layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I thought that the layout could be changed but taken into account your comments it is not possible (the code could be simplified a lot without that layout).

You are using the [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method to get the following siblings and this includes all of them (also the `ParentsourcefileCheckBox` ones).

Just change it by the [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method and it will stop in the selector that you specify.

Change this:

```
rowWithInput = myRow.nextAll(":has('.ChildsourcefileCheckBox')")
```

By this:

```
rowWithInput = myRow.nextUntil(
    ":has('.ParentsourcefileCheckBox')",
    ":has('.ChildsourcefileCheckBox')"
)
```

Here you have your same fiddle with the change (I've simplified a bit the code):

```js
$(".ParentsourcefileCheckBox").click(function() {
  var search = "input[type=checkbox][name=sourcefileCheckBox]",
    myRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
    ischecked = myRow
      .find(search)
      .is(":checked"),
    rowWithInput = myRow.nextUntil(
      ":has('.ParentsourcefileCheckBox')",
      ":has('.ChildsourcefileCheckBox')"
    );

  rowWithInput
    .find(search)
    .prop({
      "checked": ischecked,
      "disabled": ischecked
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-framed" id="seconDTable" style="display:block;height: 100%;">
  <tbody id="secondtbody">
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="checker" id="uniform- CheckBox">
          <span>
            <input
              title="Select All Bookmarks"
              class="styled"
              id="CheckBox"
              type="checkbox"
              permission="0"
            />
          </span>
        </div>
        <span>Select All</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ParentsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="LEAD Technologies" permission="0" />
        <span>LEAD Technologies</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="About LEAD Technologies" permission="0" />
        <span>About LEAD Technologies</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Fast Facts" permission="0" />
        <span>Fast Facts</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Developer Tools" permission="0" />
        <span>Developer Tools</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Imaging Applications/Utilities" permission="0" />
        <span>Imaging Applications/Utilities</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ParentsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Why Use LEADTOOLS" permission="0" />
        <span>Why Use LEADTOOLS</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="Time-Tested" permission="0" />
        <span>Time-Tested</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="myRow">
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sourcefileCheckBox" class="ChildsourcefileCheckBox" id="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="One SDK Vendor Who Does it All!" permission="0" />
        <span>One SDK Vendor Who Does it All!</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks You! ElChiniNet